# I need to get only the value outside the tag with the selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this case:

```
<li>
    <label>Sales Tax:</label>
    $204.61
</li>
```

I need to get only the value outside the label "$204.61" label **with the selectors**. I tired with

```
$( "li:last").text()
```

but the result is

> Sales Tax:
>   $204.61

```js
$("li:last").text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>Sales Tax:</label> $204.61
</li>
```

Comment: Obvious question: Can you change the html, eg to `<li><label>Sales Tax:</label><span>$204.61</span></li>`

Comment: if instead of getting item by type or position like in the answers, you want to remove a specific element, you can do like this: `$("li").html().replace($("li label")[0].outerHTML, '');` ("li label" being the selector for element to remove)

Comment: I can not change html. I just have to put the numeric value in a json file for an android app, where there is the web view with these values in question. An alternative is to use a regex in the java code, but I wonder if I can use some selector

Answer (score 3):

Filter out the text nodes and then get its text content.

```js
var text = $('li:last')
  // get all child nodes including textnodes
  .contents()
  // filterout text nodes
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  })
  // get text content and trim out leading and trailing space
  .text().trim();

// or in case structure is same then use
var text1 = $('li:last')
  .contents()
  // get the last node which is the text
  .last()
  .text().trim();

console.log(text);
console.log(text1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Sales Tax:</label> $204.61
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** With pure JavaScript (assumes to get only the last text node)

```js
// if there is only single ul then you can use
// var last = document.querySelector('li:last-child');

// get all li tags
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
// get the last li
var last = lis[lis.length - 1];
// get the last child node and then its text conetent
var text = last.childNodes[last.childNodes.length - 1].textContent.trim();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Sales Tax:</label> $204.61
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** Anyway, it's better to wrap the element with a `span` for getting the text in a simple way.

```js
var text = $('li:last span').text();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Sales Tax:</label> <span>$204.61</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using complicated html querying, it is better adjust html to better fit your needs. As @freedomn-m wrote, change html to following:

```
<li>
 <label>Sales Tax:</label>
 <span>$204.61</span>
</li>
```

And your script will look like this:

```
$( "li:last span").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why change html code a bit.This make work easy.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var result = $('li:last span').text();
  console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label>Sales Tax:</label>
  <span>$204.61</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This NOT an answer to your question but just an experiment that I think is somewhat relevant.

I **realize** you want to **collect** the data as opposed to just trying to *hide some parts of it.*

But this got me thinking if you *can* actually hide some parts of it **using CSS**

Again, this is more of an **experiment** but [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-mask-image) says this will work for at least 89% of users as of now. I tested both Chrome and FF and all is well. IE / Edge are not supported.

```css
li {
  margin-left: -5.5em;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)5.5em, /** <---- Use this to determine the cutoff point **/
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label>Sales Tax:</label> $204.61
</li>
```